# Bash for loop with multiline output from a command

Tags: bash, for-loop, mysql, multiline

I have to write a small multithreaded mysqldump script for our database and I got some problems because of a single table containing a space.

My first attempt was quite easy:

```
for TABLE in `mysql -u user -ppassword -e 'show tables;' dbname`  
do
    while [ 1 ]
    do
        if [ `jobs -r | wc -l` -lt $MAXTHREADS ]
        then
            break
        else
            sleep 1
        fi
    done

    mysqldump -u user -ppassword dbname $TABLE
done
```

Unfortunetely there was a table which contained a space. I googled a little bit for using the for loop with multiline output from commands and changing the $IFS variable was a common solution. So I changed it to \n\b (somehow $IFS was empty when I only used \n) but that was a bad idea because it caused the mysql commands to not work anymore.

I thought that this shouldn't be a problem when I get the tables beforehand and change the $IFS back everytime I use mysqldump in the for loop. But again I was mistaken as I only have one line of all tables now.
My current code:

```
TABLES=$(mysql -u user -ppassword -e "show tables" dbname | tail -n +2)

OIFS="$IFS"
AIFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
IFS="$AIFS"

for TABLE in "$TABLES"
do
    IFS="$OIFS"
    while [ 1 ]
    do
        if [ `jobs -r | wc -l` -lt $MAXTHREADS ]
        then
            break
        else
            sleep 1
        fi
    done

    mysqldump -u user -ppassword dbname $TABLE
    IFS="$AIFS"

done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

When I try to echo the $TABLES variable I get one table per line, but the for loop is only running once with the $TABLE variable containing ALL the tables.

Thanks in advance
kiro

Comment: To set `IFS` to a newline in Bash: `IFS=$'\n'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a while loop instead of for:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword -e "show tables" dbname | tail -n +2 | while read TABLE
do
    ...
done
```

...unless you need to set any variables inside the loop and have them available after the loop exits.  Since this makes the while loop part of a pipeline, it runs in a subshell, and variables and such don't transfer to the main shell.  If you need the loop to run in the main shell, you can use bash's process substitution feature instead of a standard pipe:

```
while read TABLE
do
    ...
done < <(mysql -u user -ppassword -e "show tables" dbname | tail -n +2)
```